# How do I use DLLImport with structs as parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

All the examples I can find using DLLImport to call C++ code from C# passes ints back and forth. I can get those examples working just fine. The method I need call takes two structs as its import parameters, and I'm not exactly clear how I can make this work.

Here's what I've got to work with:

I own the C++ code, so I can make any changes/additions to it that I need to.

A third party application is going to load my DLL on startup and expects the DLLExport to be defined a certain way, so i can't really change the method signature thats getting exported.

The C# app I'm building is going to be used as a wrapper so i can integrate this C++ piece into some of our other applications, which are all written in C#.

The C++ method signature I need to call looks like this

```
DllExport int Calculate (const MathInputStuctType *input, 
    MathOutputStructType *output, void **formulaStorage)
```

And MathInputStructType is defined as the following

```
typedef struct MathInputStuctTypeS {
    int             _setData;
    double              _data[(int) FieldSize];
    int             _setTdData;
} MathInputStuctType;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MSDN topic [Passing Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbckfbz.aspx) has a good introduction to passing structures to unmanaged code.  You'll also want to look at [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx), and [Marshaling Arrays of Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd93y453.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

From the declaration you posted, your C# code will look something like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
static extern int Calculate(ref MathInputStructType input,
    ref MathOutputStructType output, ref IntPtr formulaStorage);
```

Depending on the structure of MathInputStructType and MathOutputStructType in C++, you are going to have to attribute those structure declarations as well so that they marshal correctly.

Comment: "you are going to have to attribute those structure declarations as well so that they marshal correctly."

Right, this is the part that I don't really understand. I added the struct to my question.

Answer (score 3):

For the struct:

```
struct MathInputStuctType 
{
    int       _setData;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = FieldSize)]
    double[]  _data;
    int       _setTdData;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's 100% necessary but you should set the ArraySubType to UnmanagedType.R8 for the _data field.

Comment: That should be inferred (I assume, as the marshaller is pretty good).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at this project on CodePlex, http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120.  It should help you marshal the structures correctly.

Comment: This looks cool and all, but no matter what DLL I choose, it keeps telling me that expects a manifest. Looks like a cool tool if it worked though.

Comment: Didn't know it was that restrictive, sorry about that.

Comment: Instead of trying to open a DLL, you can use the SigImp Translate Snippet tab to see how a certain C++ code should be defined in C#.